# Set cookie to menu jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code:

I have two buttons and two list. This is my code code:

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.select-user-type-js', function() {
  $('.select-user-type-js.active').add($(this)).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).hasClass('select-user-type_customer')) {
    $('#buyer').show();
    $('#seller').hide();
  } else {
    $('#buyer').hide();
    $('#seller').show();
  }
});

$(document).on("click", ".select-user-type-js", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('select-user-type_customer')) {
    $.cookie("tab", 'select-user-type_customer');
  } else {
    $.cookie("tab", 'select-user-type_performer');
  }
});

if ($.cookie("select-user-type_customer")) {
  $('#buyer')).show();
$('#seller').hide();
$('.select-user-type_performer').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
}
else {
  $('#seller')).show();
$('#buyer').hide();
$('.select-user-type_customer').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" class="select-user-type-js select-user-type_customer active">Customer</a>
<a href="" id="seller" class="select-user-type-js select-user-type_performer">Seller</a>

<ul id="buyer">
  <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="seller" style="display: none;">
  <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #3</a></li>
</ul>
```

How I can write to cookie menu? When user reload to page, to save the menu that he chose, when clicking to specific button..? My Code is not working for cookie

Comment: again you have misspells in your code `$('#seller'))` And AGAIN you have duplicated `id="seller"`

Comment: And? It does not work because of it!

Comment: You're confusing the name and value of the cookie. You're setting a cookie called `tab` to a value `select-user-type_customer` or `select-user-type_performer`. Then you're testing for a cookie *named* `select-user-type_customer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a79f0fcg/1/) of your example with `Cookie`

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.select-user-type-js', function() {
  $('.select-user-type-js.active').add($(this)).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).hasClass('select-user-type_customer')) {
    $('#buyer').show();
    $('#seller').hide();
  } else {
    $('#buyer').hide();
    $('#seller').show();
  }
});

$(document).on("click", ".select-user-type-js", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  if ($(this).hasClass('select-user-type_customer')) {
    Cookies.set("tab", 'select-user-type_customer');
  } else {
    Cookies.set("tab", 'select-user-type_performer');
  }
});

if (Cookies.get("tab") == 'select-user-type_customer') {
  $('#buyer').show();
  $('#seller').hide();
  $('.select-user-type_customer').addClass('active');
} else {
  $('#seller').show();
  $('#buyer').hide();
  $('.select-user-type_performer').AddClass('active');
}
```

when you need to check the cookie value you have to do `Cookies.get("tab") == 'select-user-type_customer'` and not `Cookies.get("select-user-type_customer")`

Comment: try look at the demo now